# In perl, how can I find out the module where a specific exported function is defined?

Tags: perl, debugging, perl-module

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Perl, how can I check from which module a given function was imported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684930/in-perl-how-can-i-check-from-which-module-a-given-function-was-imported)

Is it possible to find out the module or file where a specific perl function was defined?

For example, let's say you have a perl script that imports several modules, and one of the modules exports a function named foo() using Exporter's @EXPORT array.  How can I programmatically determine the module where foo() was defined?

I tried the following:

```
use YAML;
sub identify_typeglob {
    my $glob = shift;
    print 'You gave me ', *{$glob}{PACKAGE}, '::', *{$glob}{NAME}, "\n";
}
identify_typeglob *Dump;
```

But that just gives me `main::Dump`, even though the actual source of the function is `YAML::Dump`.

Comment: Yep, that answers my question.  Sorry about the duplicate.