# getting method's source file location from inside the code

Tags: perl

Is there a way in **perl**, to get the **source file location** of a method ?
For example if method - "myMathod" from module "methodModule" is invoked from perl script - "myScript" . And lets say 'myModule' resides in path : /path/to/myModule,
so is there a way to do something like this :
getSourceFileLocationOf("methodModule") == "/path/to/myModule"

Comment: You can check the `%INC` hash which has the full file path of each used module:  `perl -e 'use Data::Dumper; print Dumper(\%INC);'`

Comment: Another example: `perl -e 'use WWW::Mechanize; print $INC{"WWW/Mechanize.pm"} . "\n";'`

Answer (score 2):

You can check inside the `%INC` hash as documented in [perldoc perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html):

> %INC
>
> The hash %INC contains entries for each filename included via the do, require, or use operators. The key is the filename you specified (with module names converted to pathnames), and the value is the location of the file found. The require operator uses this hash to determine whether a particular file has already been included.
>
> If the file was loaded via a hook (e.g. a subroutine reference, see require for a description of these hooks), this hook is by default inserted into %INC in place of a filename. Note, however, that the hook may have set the %INC entry by itself to provide some more specific info.

Here is a simple example:

```
perl -e 'use WWW::Mechanize; print $ENV{"WWW/Mechanize.pm"} . "\n";
```

**output**

```
/usr/local/share/perl5/WWW/Mechanize.pm
```

As suggested by @zdim, there is also the rather user-friendly [Sub::Identify](http://search.cpan.org/%7Ergarcia/Sub-Identify-0.14/lib/Sub/Identify.pm) which can be used:

```
use Sub::Identify qw( :all );
use WWW::Mechanize;

my ($file, $line) = get_code_location( \&WWW::Mechanize::get );
print "File $file, Line $line\n";'
```

**output**

```
File /usr/local/share/perl5/WWW/Mechanize.pm, Line 106
```

Comment: While you can find the module's name from the sub's name [using `Devel::Peek`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3684995/4653379)

Comment: This doesn't tell you which source file contains the definition of a given method unless there is no inheritance.

Comment: And there is also [Sub::Identify](http://search.cpan.org/~rgarcia/Sub-Identify-0.14/lib/Sub/Identify.pm) and, better yet, [Sub::Util](http://search.cpan.org/~pevans/Scalar-List-Utils-1.49/lib/Sub/Util.pm)

Comment: With `Sub::Identify` and `Sub::Util` it's one simple call,  `sub_name` or `subname`.  So they can query with the sub name, and then do the `%INC` bit. (`Devel::Peek` does involve more.)

Comment: Thank you very much ! and if the method is from another perl file (.pl) and not module , will these solutions also work ?

Answer (score 1):

To find the package in which the method was found:

```
use mro          qw( );
use Scalar::Util qw( blessed );

sub get_method_package {
   my ($obj, $method_name) = @_;
   defined( my $class = blessed($obj) )
      or return undef;

   for my $pkg_name (@{ mro::get_linear_isa($class) }) {
      my $pkg = do {
         no strict qw( refs );
         *{ $pkg_name.'::'.$method_name }
      };
      return $pkg_name if *{$pkg}{CODE};
   }

   return undef;
}
```

Note: Doesn't work if the method is autoloaded.

---

To find the package in which the method was compiled:

```
use B qw( svref_2object );

sub get_method_package {
   my ($obj, $method_name) = @_;
   my $method_ref = $obj->can($method_name)
      or return undef;

   return svref_2object($method_ref)->GV->STASH->NAME;
}
```

Note: Only works for autoloaded methods if can is properly overridden.

Note: Works for methods implemented in XS.

---

To find the file in which the method was compiled:

```
use B qw( svref_2object );

sub get_method_file {
   my ($obj, $method_name) = @_;
   my $method_ref = $obj->can($method_name)
      or return undef;

   return svref_2object($method_ref)->FILE;
}
```

Note: Only works for autoloaded methods if can is properly overridden.

Note: Only works well for Perl methods. For methods implemented in XS, it returns the name of the .c file with no path. For example, returns `XS.c` for `JSON::XS->encode`. (This may vary by system, and by XS loader.)